# HTML5 JavaScript canvas animation class method called within function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having trouble drawing an animation on a HTML 5 canvas inside a loop.  I have created a javascript animation function/class that stores frames and duration information and provides a get function to getFrame()[returns image] sub-function to retrieve the relevant frame.  This works perfectly fine so i haven't included the full script.  If anyone wants or needs it i will send to you.

When i call the following code it displays the animation as intended.

```
canvas.drawImage(tile1a.getFrame(),50,60);
canvas.drawImage(tile1a.getFrame(),50,90);
canvas.drawImage(tile1a.getFrame(),50,120);
//etc
```

This isn't very efficient as i want to draw a lot of tiles is column so it would be better to use a for loop.  Therefore i tried the following code but the page just keeps crashing.

```
for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        canvas.drawImage(tile1a.getFrame(),FIELD_WIDTH,i*30);
    }
```

However, i then tried the following which worked:

```
var temp = tile1a.getFrame();
for (i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        canvas.drawImage(temp,FIELD_WIDTH,i*30);
    }
```

So the problem is definitely something to with me calling getFrame() within the for loop.  I recon it is probably something really stupid but i can't figure it out!

Any help is much appreciated.
thanks
Jason

Comment: What error message do you get when it crashes?

Comment: @sdleihssirhc it is a google chrome error along the lines on the pageis unresponsive.

Comment: Can you link to a live example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The loop in your `draw` function is set up like this:

```
for (i=1; i<=10; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Notice that you didn't create the `i` variable with the `var` keyword! That means that it will be a global variable!

Now look at the loop in your `getFrame` function:

```
for (i=0; i<this.frames.length; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

The `i` in that loop is *also* global...

Your `getFrame` function is making sure that `i` will always be reset to 4 (because you only have four frames in it)!

The quick fix is to add some `var`s:

```
// in the `draw` function, for example
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Also worth noting that the function being in a for loop calls the function each time. If performance is an issue for you it'll be much more efficient to call it once before the for loop.

Comment: Nice; I often am hard-pressed to come up with a real-world case where a global loop var would be a problem, but here we have just such a case.